# Parsing complex xml CDATA in c# in windows 8 phone app

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, linq-to-xml, cdata

I am trying to read to some data in XML format which is CDATA in my windows 8 phone app. Here is a sample of the data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE HolyQuran [
<!ATTLIST HolyQuran TranslationID CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST HolyQuran Writer CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST HolyQuran Language CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST HolyQuran LanguageIsoCode CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST HolyQuran Direction (rtl|ltr) #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT HolyQuran (Chapter+)>
<!ATTLIST Chapter ChapterID CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST Chapter ChapterName CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT Chapter (Verse+)>
<!ATTLIST Verse VerseID CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT Verse (#PCDATA)>
  ]>
<!-- This SQL Query Generated at 22 November 2013 01:44 (UTC) from
  www.qurandatabase.org -->
<HolyQuran TranslationID="59" Writer="Yusuf Ali" Language="English"
    LanguageIsoCode="eng" Direction="ltr">
<Chapter ChapterID="1" ChapterName="The Opening">
    <Verse VerseID="1"><![CDATA[In the name of Allah, Most Gracious, Most
                          Merciful.]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="2"><![CDATA[Praise be to Allah, the Cherisher and Sustainer
                          of the worlds;]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="3"><![CDATA[Most Gracious, Most Merciful;]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="4"><![CDATA[Master of the Day of Judgment.]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="5"><![CDATA[Thee do we worship, and Thine aid we seek.
                         ]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="6"><![CDATA[Show us the straight way,]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="7"><![CDATA[The way of those on whom Thou hast bestowed Thy
                         Grace, those whose (portion) is not wrath, and who go
                         not astray.]]></Verse>
</Chapter>
<Chapter ChapterID="114" ChapterName="The Men">
<Verse VerseID="1"><![CDATA[Say: I seek refuge with the Lord and Cherisher 
             of Mankind,]]></Verse>
<Verse VerseID="2"><![CDATA[The King (or Ruler) of Mankind,]]></Verse>
<Verse VerseID="3"><![CDATA[The god (or judge) of Mankind,-]]></Verse>
<Verse VerseID="4"><![CDATA[From the mischief of the Whisperer (of Evil), who 
                         withdraws (after his whisper),-]]></Verse>
<Verse VerseID="5"><![CDATA[(The same) who whispers into the hearts of Mankind,-]]>  
    </Verse>
<Verse VerseID="6"><![CDATA[Among Jinns and among men.]]></Verse>
</Chapter>
</HolyQuran>
```

I want to get a data structure which contains the the whole book with sub data structures for chapters to contain ChapterName, ChapterID and a List of all the verse contents and their corresponding VerseIDs for that particular chapter. Please note that by verse content, I mean the CDATA. I need to use XDocument but I cannot figure out how to parse this complex XML.

I will greatly appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use XML serialization: define classes that match the structure of the XML document, with attributes that describe the XML schema, and use the `XmlSerializer` class to parse the input.

In your case the classes would look like that:

```
public class HolyQuran
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int TranslationID { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Writer { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Language { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string LangIsoCode { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Direction { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Chapter")]
    public List<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
}

public class Chapter
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int ChapterID { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ChapterName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Verse")]
    public List<Verse> Verses { get; set; }
}

public class Verse
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int VerseId { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And you can use the following code to parse the file:

```
static HolyQuran LoadQuran(string path)
{
    var readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore };
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(path, readerSettings))
    {
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(HolyQuran));
        return (HolyQuran)xs.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

You don't have to do anything special to parse the CDATA sections, the `XmlReader` already knows how to handle them.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I cannot declare the classes for some reason because it is not recognizing the [XmlAttribute] part?